# webdriver-manager won't start - Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Iv'e seen some posts about this error here and there, but no one seemed to solve mine.
[image: The error I get after webdriver-manager start:]

It seems to fail even after adding `C:\Windows\System32` to the Enviormental Variables.

Comment: Have you check the JDK version under your account and administrator?  Maybe the selenium-standalone.jar needs JDK >= 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runninng the cmd as administrator solved this.
not sure why.

Comment: This might be because you need to run java with admin permissions.